# Task Scheduler with ADFS loggin

Tags: task-manager

I have a Windows 7 PC with ADFS login.
When I create a *Task* with the *Task Scheduler* with the option *Run only when user is logged on* everything is fine.
But then I choose: *Run whether user is logged on or not* nothing happens, even I’m logged or not.

What I'm missing?

Edit:
Also the *Last Run Time* reports that it had run on the desired time with `0x0` code, but actually no action executed.

Exported task that doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-11-06T16:22:01.9684545</Date>
    <Author>workgroup\username</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2014-11-06T16:24:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>workgroup\username</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>Parallel</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Exported task (changed part) that work:

```
<Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>workgroup\username</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
```

And if I change the `<RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>` I have the same results.

Chrome is used as an example.

Comment: So it doesn't run at all (according to the Task Scheduler's "Last Run Time")? Or does the task run, but you're not seeing the effect that you expect from the task?

Comment: Sorry for the inadequate info. The Last Run Time reports that it had run on the desired time, but actually no action executed.

Comment: Does it also give you a Last Run Result of 0x0 (which means "success" BTW :) ).  Also, are you specifying the user account to run the task as?  Did you check mark "run with highest privileges" by any chance?